# How to repeat a jquery animation?

Tags: jquery

So basically I have this JQuery code (see below). at the moment the animation gets played once after 9 seconds but I want it to play it 3 times and within those 3 times there should be a delay. Could someone help me out please as I am new to JQuery? Thanks!

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var ratio = 0.5;
        $('.resized-splitflap').splitFlap({
            charWidth:  25 * ratio,
            charHeight: 50 * ratio,
            imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
        });

            $('.resized-newyork').splitFlap({
            charWidth:  25 * ratio,
            charHeight: 50 * ratio,
            imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
        });
                    $('.resized-dublin').splitFlap({
            charWidth:  25 * ratio,
            charHeight: 50 * ratio,
            imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
        });
        }, 9 * 1000);
  });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

call `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout` for recurring callback function execution after definite time interval/delay.

Simple example of repeated calling of same function using `setInterval()`

**JS Code:**

```
  var loop = 0;
var id = setInterval(function() {
  loop++;
  if(loop === 3)
  {
    clearInterval(id);
  }
  alert(" loop: "+loop);
}, 1000);
```

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Svx3n/112/**

*Note: Keep in mind to clear the setInterval() when not required, as it may cause abnormal behaviour & may slowdown the javascript engine.*

Comment: tough to understand ,could you update or create a new jsfiddle which showcases your issue,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: it wont allow you to see the animation. Is it possible for you to download the github file and then try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this:
First wrap all your animations in a function.
Then on document ready just call:

```
yourFunctionWithAllAnimations()
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            setTimeout(function() { yourFunctionWithAllAnimations() },3000)
        }
```

first call is without delay, the next two calls are with a delay of 3000ms = 3 sec

Answer (score 0):

This answer is somehow extended version of **@dreamweiver**:

```
  var ratio = 0.5;
  var arr = $('.sameclass').map(function(){ return this.id; }).get();
  var loop = 0;
  var id = setInterval(function() {
    $('#'+arr[loop]).splitFlap({ // select the id in the arr here.
        charWidth:  25 * ratio,
        charHeight: 50 * ratio,
        imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
    });
    loop++; // increment the loop value here
    if(loop === 3){
      clearInterval(id);
    }
    }, 9 * 1000);
```

---

What i want to suggest you that just put a same class to all the divs you want to *splitFlap* and current class name change to ids for them like this:

```
<div class='sameclass' id='resized-splitflap'></div>
<div class='sameclass' id='resized-newyork'></div>
<div class='sameclass' id='resized-dublin'></div>
```

then you can make them to put in array as i suggested in `var arr`. Then you can make use of `setInterval` as above.

Comment: This code plays each animation at a time. I want it to play all the animations at the same time